# Pentaho Kettle ETL tool validation using table schema as input

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I am trying to create a transformation to validate data obtained on the table input step , which is then written to a text file. I want this transformation to be generic, that is I should be able to use different table name parameters to run the transformation and get the text file output. How do I accomplish the validation part to do this. So far I have been able to validate only one table input., when I give a different table name I get an error, as the validator cannot find he earlier table's fields to validate

Comment: Read up on the ETL Metadata Injection step. See if that will work for you.

Comment: @coldmarble can you tell me what sort of data validation you r doing in here... any particular step or plugin u r using to validate??